# How do you select values from a SQL column in Python

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas

I have a column called `REQUIREDCOLUMNS` in a SQL database which contains the columns which I need to select in my Python script below.

**Excerpt of Current Code:**

```
db = mongo_client.get_database(asqldb_row.SCHEMA_NAME)
coll = db.get_collection(asqldb_row.TABLE_NAME) 
table = list(coll.find())
root = json_normalize(table)
```

The `REQUIREDCOLUMNS`in SQL contains values `reportId`, `siteId`, `price`, `location`

So instead of explicitly typing:

`print(root[["reportId","siteId","price","location"]])`

Is there a way to do `print(root[REQUIREDCOLUMNS])`?

Note: *(I'm already connected to the SQL database in my python script)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use cursors if you are using mysql or pymysql , both the syntax are almost similar below i will mention for mysql

```
import mysql
import mysql.connector

db = mysql.connector.connect(
   host = "localhost",
    user = "root",
    passwd = "  ",
    database = "  "
)

cursor = db.cursor()
sql="select REQUIREDCOLUMNS from table_name"
cursor.execute(sql)
required_cols = cursor.fetchall()#this wll give ["reportId","siteId","price","location"] 

cols_as_string=','.join(required_cols)
new_sql='select '+cols_as_string+' from table_name'

cursor.execute(new_sql)
result=cursor.fetchall()
```

This should probably work, i intentionally split many lines into several lines for understanding.
syntax could be slightly different for pymysql

Comment: so in regards to the question as i'm referring to `SQL Server` would this method still work? i'm using `pyodbc` to connect to `SQL Server`